# find specific array value C# using user input microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, user-input

Hi Guys looking for a solution to make a method that uses user input to find a specific array value based on users input for week and day input this is my code for my user input and array which is a 2d array:

```
    public int[,] ToysMade = new int[4, 5];
    public String[] days = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

    //retrieve method based from user input
    public void retrieveDay()
    {
        String input1;
        String input2;
        int num;

        input1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter week number: ", "Enter Value");
        input2 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter day number: ", "Enter Value");

        try
        {
            while (!(int.TryParse(input1, out num)))
            {

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        txtOutput.Text += "\r\nRetrieve products completed on a specific day \r\nProducts Completed on that day are: " + " \r\n";
    }

    //Get user input method via microsoft.vb inputbox 
    public void UserInput()
    {
        String value;
        int numCount;


        //retrieveing length of ToysMade array dimensions if less than 0 repeat untill last dimension filled
        for (int i = 0; i < ToysMade.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ToysMade.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //taking user input for array dimension 0 "first dimension" then increment it by 1 after input ready for next dimension "i + 1"
                value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Value For " + days[j] + " of week " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Enter Value");

                try
                {
                    //making sure for only int past through 
                    while (!(int.TryParse(value, out numCount)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number, please try again.");
                        value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Value for " + days[i] + " of week " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Enter Value");
                    }
                    // taking values enterd from user and set next dimension for next input by incrementing it
                    ToysMade[i, j] = numCount;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value enterd is not in a valid format");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, What you trying to do?

Comment: hi un-lucky i have a 2d array set that currently fills the arrays using user input and i need to be able to also search for a specific array via the user input they first put in which day and which week.

Comment: i added my code that fills my arrays with user input hopefully it makes it clear

Comment: So you want the user to enter a 4X5 matrix through InputBox. I sincerely hope This will irritate the user. There may be some better way to achieve this

Comment: its part of my study requirements and has asked me to do this in such a way